# How to eliminate the space between the section / footer in a responsive manner?

Tags: html, css

I have a space showing in between my main content section and footer, causing an unnecessary scroll bar to be present in order to view the footer (after some dead space).

I've tried manually changing heights etc. of elements but had no luck, also experimented with overflow:y on various elements but they haven't had the desired effect. I'd like the index.html page to scale to display size, with the footer at the bottom (no x-axis scroll bar).

Please could someone save me from insanity! I'm guessing this has a simple remedy, I'm only using HTML / CSS. Thanks!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4utOR.png)

Link to JSFiddle in the comments below.

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Spicyherb/zj5098kw/)

Comment: Please make use of the built in Code Snippets to share code. There's a reason we don't allow JSFiddle links alone for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The space is caused by the property "padding-bottom: 100%;" on "embed-container" (on row 238 in your stylesheet). Removing this property removes the gap completely.

Not quite sure what you mean by "in a responsive manner", but I hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, the answer was as trivial as I though - I've been looking in all of the wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove in the class `.embed-container` these property `padding-bottom: 100%;`.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to paddings and margins in your styles.

`padding-bottom: 100%`  in  `.embed-container`  and `margin:30px` in `.driver-quote, .summary` classes. You need adjust the `margins` and `paddings` properly.

Sample Code I added.
[Sample Code](https://jsfiddle.net/25mortek/1/)

Answer (score 0):

delete the `padding-bottom: 100%;`